# Function might not be defined at runtim

Tags: byte-compilation

To use `directory-files-recursively` in Emacs 24.x, I'm [adding the following](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/pull/2057/files#diff-68726d397391af81b790f27cf82df8b8R158) to a file `cider-compat.el`:

```el
(eval-and-compile
  (unless (fboundp 'directory-files-recursively)
    (defun directory-files-recursively (dir regexp &optional include-directories)
      ...)))
```

Byte-compiling the file, however, gives [an error](https://travis-ci.org/clojure-emacs/cider/jobs/255846466) in Emacs 24.x:

```
In toplevel form:
cider-compat.el:191:1:Error: the function `directory-files-recursively' might not be defined at runtime.
make: *** [cider-compat.elc-test] Error 1
```

Why is this? The `eval-and-compile` seems to work fine for other `defun`s, e.g. `internal--build-binding`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the compiler simply sees that at compile-time the function is defined (because of the `eval-and-`), but it sees that at runtime, the function will only be defined `(if <blabla>`, IOW it will only be defined in some circumstances, and it doesn't bother to try to figure out what those circumstances would be, so it emits the warning because of the doubt.

You can typically avoid these kinds of issues (and avoid `eval-and-compile` as well, which tends to be a bit quirky) with:

```
(defalias 'my-directory-files-recursively
  (if (fboundp 'directory-files-recursively
      'directory-files-recursively)
    (lambda (dir regexp &optional include-directories)
      ...)))
```

Comment: That's one solution, but a `with-no-warnings` around the body seems to work as well.

Comment: Better than `with-no-warning` (which is a blunt tool), if you only want to silence the warning rather than make the code understandable to the compiler, you can use `declare-function`.